# Airflow: How to set globally default emails for tasks failures?

Tags: python, airflow

In my environment most of the task failure alerts should be sent to the specific list of developers/groups of developers.

I can pass these emails into every DAG like:

```py
default_args = {
    'email': ['dev1@test.com', 'dev2@test.com', 'dev3@test.com'],
    ...
}

with DAG(
    'TestDagWithEmail',
    default_args=default_args,
    ...
) as dag:
  ...
```

But is there any option to get rid of specifying `'email'` in every DAG I create (with the ability to override when needed)?
I was looking for some setting in `airflow.cfg`, but had no luck.

Airflow version: 1.10.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, there is no config for emails but you could use Cluster Policy for task mutation hook as below:

Read More: https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/1.10.14/concepts.html#cluster-policies-for-task-mutation

```py
def policy(task):
    task.email = ['dev1@test.com', 'dev2@test.com', 'dev3@test.com']
```

Comment: Seems like a solution, is it enough to add `is None` check to enable `email` overriding for a specific DAG with `default_args`? Like this: `if task.email is None: task.email = [...]`